# default values from not defined constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

*Bjarne wrote:-*
**For  a  type  T,  T()  is  the  notation  for  the  default value , as  defined by the  default constructor** .
What happen when we don't declare default constructor ? For example

```
using namespace std;

class date{
    int n,m;
    public:
   int day(){return n;}
   int month(){return m;}
          };//no default constructor

int main()
{
     date any =date();
     cout<<any.month()<<endl;   
     cout<<any.day()<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

Output of this program is 0 and 0 every time i run my program. I haven't declare any default constructor then why there exits a default value i.e. 0?

EDIT-

```
    class date{
        int n,m;
        public:
        date (){
        m=1;}
       int day(){return n;}
       int month(){return m;}
     };

 int main()
  {
     date any =date();
     cout<<any.month()<<endl;   
     cout<<any.day()<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

After reading answers i provide a default constructor but now n is getting garbage value but according to answers it should be 0 as m is out of reach of any other constructor and it is value initialisation as mentioned in answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you see is Well-Defined for your class.

---

**How & Why is the behavior Well-Defined?**

**The rule is:**
If you do not provide a no argument constructor the compiler generates one for your program in case your program needs one.
**Caveat:**
The compiler does not generate the no argument constructor if your program defines *any* constructor for the class.

As per the C++ Standard an object can be initialized in 3 ways:

- Zero Initialization
- Default Initialization &
- Value Initialization

When, a type name or constructor initializer is followed by `()` the initialization is through value initialization.

Thus,

```
date any =date();
              ^^^
```

**Value Initializes** an nameless object and then copies it in to the local object `any`,
      while:

```
date any;
```

would be a **Default Initialization**.

Value Initialization gives an initial value of zero to members that are out of reach of any constructor.
In your program, `n` and `m` are beyond the reach of any constructor and hence get initialized to `0`.

---

**Answer to Edited Question:**
In your edited case, your class provides a no argument constructor, `date()`, which is capable(& should) initialize members `n` and `m`, but this constructor doesn't initialize both the members, So In this case no zero initialization takes place, and the uninitialized members in the object have an **Indeterminate**(any random) value, further this temporary object is copied to `any` object which displays the shows indeterminate member values.

---

**For Standerdese Fans:**
The rules for object Initialization are aptly defined in:

**C++03 Standard 8.5/5:**

> To **zero-initialize** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
>   — if T is a non-union class type, each nonstatic data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a union type, the object’s first named data member is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
>   — if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.
>
> To **default-initialize** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>   —  otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>   — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>   — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   —  otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

Comment: Using `date any;` does not initialize it. `date any = date();` will call compiler-generated default constructor which in turn will call default constructors for all base classes and members. For `int` default constructor is `int()`. And it will initialize `int` members to `0`. You can see for yourself [link](http://ideone.com/4sWwX)

Comment: @AzzA: Just because a program shows observable behavior it does not mean it is correct.Anyhow I edited the answer to add the Standard specification which explains why it works this way. And Yes, I don't mind editing my wrong answers to correct ones.

Comment: It is correct behavior. This compiler-generated default constructor will also initialize `vtable` if there is need. So this is correct and anticipated behavior.

Comment: @AzzA: Can you provide the reference from the Standard which says default constructor will initialize `v-table`? That is a sweeping statement, The standard does not mention `v-table` at all, dynamic dispatch is a implementation detail.Don't rely & base your fundamentals on observable behaviors, Undefined & Unspecified behaviors can show you any behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, `vptr`, not `vtable`. And, yes, technically, you are correct - this is implementation specific. But, say, on those implementations that put `vptr` into instances (and I don't know if there are any that don't; mainstream do that) , compiler-generated default constructor will initialize `vptr`. But, yes, since Standard leaves `vptr` up to implementation, it does not say anything about it, I suppose. Which is very useful to know.

Comment: @AzzA: To be specific, the initialization of `vptr` happens in the member initialization list of the constructor not in the constructor body.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7879/discussion-between-azza-and-als)

Comment: +1 for providing complete and adequate quote from the Standard, thus saving my (and others) time.

Comment: @AzzA: Thanks to your comment, which prompted me to do so :)

Comment: @Als: what i do next is provide a default constructor like this` date (){m=1;}` what you just said is "Value Initialization gives an initial value of zero to members that are out of reach of any constructor.In your program, n and m are beyond the reach of any constructor and hence get initialized to 0."so output should be n=0 m=1.but n is getting garbage values

Comment: @10001001058: Please edit and add your modified code at the end of Q.

Comment: @Als :please answer this question

Answer (score 4):

Because compiler, cursing under its breath, generates one for you.

EDIT: Since Als said it does not answer question, I'll elaborate. When you use `date any = date();`, you call compiler-generated default constructor. This constructor calls default constructors for all base classes and data members. For your data members `int` default constructor is `int()`, which sets value to `0`. Here is [code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/4sWwX)

```
#include <iostream>

int main( void )
{
 int i = -123;

 i = int(); 

 std::cout << i << std::endl; 


 return( 0 );
}
```

Program output:

```
0
```

Comment: @Als Yes, it does. And see my comment to your answer.

Comment: :what i do next is provide a default constructor like this` date (){m=1;}`but now n is getting garbage value . but it is not calling int() for n to make it  zero

Comment: @T.J. `date::date() : n(), m( 1 ) {}`

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ draft standard (December 1996 Working Paper):

If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly declared. An  implicitly-declared default constructor is an inline public member of its class.