# default constructor initialisation

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
class First
{
public:
    int y;
    First()
    {
        y = 90;
    }
};

class Second{
    public:
       int x;
       First ob;  //if i comment it, value of x is initialised to zero
};

int main()
{
    Second obj = Second();
    cout << obj.x << endl;
}
```

This program gives different output when I change it:

1. If I comment out the line `First ob;` then value of x is initialised to zero
2. If the class consists object of class First, then member has garbage value.
3. If I create object like `Second obj;` then it has garbage value.

What is the reason it behaves differently when Second class consists only built-in members and when object of another class?

And what is the difference between these statements:

```
Second obj = Second();
Second obj;
```

Comment: When you add a member of type `First`, the class becomes non-pod because it has a member with a non-trivial constructor. Sorry, but I can't give a more helpful answer atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1. When you comment out the line `First ob`, then `Second` class becomes a POD type, which can be value-initialized using the syntax `Second obj= Second()`, and value-initialization, in case of *built-in* types, means zero-initialized, so `x` is zero-initialized.

Case 2: When you keep the line `First ob`, then `Second` class becomes non-POD type, because `First` class is non-POD type (as it has user-defined constructor<sup>1</sup>]). In this case, the syntax `Second obj=Second()` doesn't initialize built-in data type, if you don't initialize it in the constructor.

Case 3: When write `Second obj`, then there  are again two cases (read them carefully):

- `obj` will be default constructed if there is `First ob` line. And in this case, `x` will not be initialized at all, as it is not manually initialized in the constructor of `Second`.
- `obj` will not be initialized at all if you `First ob` line is commented out. In this case, `Second` becomes a POD, and POD types are not initialized if you only write `Second obj`.

---

<sup>1</sup> See this related topic:

- [Can't C++ POD type have any constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442717/cant-c-pod-type-have-any-constructor)

Comment: How do you go from "default" to "zero" initialization in the POD case? (I somehow doubt that PODness is relevant to this question.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338881/default-values-from-not-defined-constructor/9338905#9338905)

Comment: @KerrekSB: That part of little bit incorrect. I edited it. Actually default-initialization in case of built-in types means zero-initialization.

Comment: @Als: But then `Second()` is *value*-initialization, isn't it? Not default-initialization?

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm still not convinced. Default-i of built-ins does nothing. Only *value*-i of built-in types is zero-i.

Comment: @Nawaz: I posted a little discussion about aggregates.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually, in default-initialization, objects of built-in types are zero-initialized.

Comment: @Nawaz: I think 8.5(6) disagrees with you :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ohh.. C++11 and C++03 differs here. Anyway, I've used value-initialization (instead of default-initialization) in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through the accepted answer to [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402) - without the `First` object, your class is an 'A', with it your class is a 'B'. `Second obj;` will default-initialize it, `Second obj = Second();` will value-initialize it.

This is one of the areas where C++ has some quite tricky and surprising rules, but I'm not going to cover them in detail here as they've been very well explained in the above question.

[What do the following phrases mean in C++: zero-, default- and value-initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat) is also related.

Edit:

The above links only really cover the initialization side of things, not the rules on what makes a class trivial/POD/standard layout/etc. [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) covers that side of things.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being a bit tangential, let me post a modified version of the problem, along with a discussion. Let's consider these classes:

```
struct Agatha
{
    int x;
};

struct Claire
{
    Claire() { }
    int x;
};
```

To simplify the initialization syntax and make the example analyzable with Valgrind, let's use dynamic objects:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Agatha> p1(new Agatha);     // #1d
    std::unique_ptr<Agatha> p2(new Agatha());   // #1v

    std::unique_ptr<Claire> q1(new Claire);     // #2d
    std::unique_ptr<Claire> q2(new Claire());   // #2v


    std::cout << p1->x
              << p2->x
              << q1->x
              << q2->x
              << std::endl;
}
```

Only **one** of those printing lines is correct! Can you figure out which one?

The answer is #1v. Let's discuss:

- Case #1d default-initializes an aggregate, which default-initializes each member, which default-initializes `Agatha::x`, which leaves it uninitialized.
- Case #1v value-initializes a aggregate, which value-initializes all members, and thus value-initializes `Agatha::x`, and thus zero-initializes it. (This is the good case.)
- Case #2d default-initializes a non-aggregate, which calls the default constructor. The default constructor of `Claire` does *not* initialize `Claire::x`, so it is left uninitialized.
- Case #2d value-initialization of a non-aggregate also calls the default constructor, and the situation is identical to #2v.

Notice that the whole discussion has nothing to do with PODness, but merely with whether the class is an aggregate, like `Agatha`, or a non-trivial class type with like `Claire`. You could add a member of type `std::string` to `Agatha` without affecting this example.